# How to extract a nested tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract 'span' tag from 'p' but I don't know how to do it

```
html = "
<div id="tab-description" class="plugin-description section">
    <h2 id="description-header">Description</h2>
    <p><span class="embed-youtube" style="text-align:center; display: block;"><iframe class="youtube-player"src="https://www.youtube.com/"></iframe></span></p>
</div>
"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
description = soup.find(id="tab-description").find('p')
```

I tried to `decompose()` it but returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

To get `<span>` select it directly:

```
soup.find(id="tab-description").p.span
```

or

```
soup.find(id="tab-description").find('span')
```

or

```
soup.select_one('#tab-description p > span')
```

**Be aware** *Not an option to scrape contents from the `<iframe>`, if this should be the intension. If so? This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus.*

---

To delete `<span>` and its contents from `soup`:

```
soup.find(id="tab-description").p.span.decompose()
```

Comment: I need to delete it from <p>

Comment: what about using -> `soup.find(id="tab-description").p.span.decompose()`